# Elasticsearch document aliases

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I have multiple mappings which come from the same datasource but have small differences, like the example below.

```
{
  "type_A" : {
    "properties" : {
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string"
      }
      "meta_A" : {
        "type" : "string"
      }
    }
  }
}


{
  "type_B" : {
    "properties" : {
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string"
      }
      "meta_B" : {
        "type" : "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to be able to is:

- Directly query specific fields (like meta_A)
- Directly query all documents from the datsource
- Query all documents from a specific mapping

What I was looking into is the type filter, so preferably I could write a query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "type" : { "value" : "unified_type" }
      }
    }
    // other query clauses
  }
}
```

So instead of typing `"type_A"`,`"type_B"` in an or clause in the type filter I would like to have this `"unified_type"`, but without giving up the possibility to directly query `"type_A"`.

How could I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's possible. However, you could use [`copy_to`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html?q=copy_to) functionality, so you would have your fields as they are now and their values copied into unified name.

> The `copy_to` parameter allows you to create custom [_all](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) fields. In
>   other words, the values of multiple fields can be copied into a group
>   field, which can then be queried as a single field. For instance, the
>   `first_name` and `last_name` fields can be copied to the `full_name` field
>   as follows:

So you'd be copying both `"meta_A"` and `"meta_B"` into some `"unified_meta"` field and query this one.

Comment: While this is certainly I nice feature that I wasn't aware of until now it is not useful for me. I would need the copy-to on a document level to query a unified (preferably at query time) mapping. I'll edit the question to make it a bit clearer.